# Método que ejecuta el Toolbar que nos crea andriod studio por defecto

Tags: java, android

estoy empezando en android y estoy construyendo una aplicación con android studio. Al crear los activity he seleccionado la opción del BasicActivity y éste me crea una toolbar superior de forma automática. Lo que me gustaría saber es que método lanza la opción de "volver atás" del toolbar para poder sobrescribirlo, ya que he estado buscando y no he dado con el método que se ejecuta, casi siempre veo referencias al onBackPressed(), pero no es este, ya que trato de sobrescribirlo y no me ejecuta la acción.

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    System.out.println("REALIZA METODO SOBREESCRITO");
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

A parte del método, me gustaría también saber como podría seleccionar la vista de la flecha del toolbar o como hacer referencia a ella.

Gracias de antemano.

**Edito:** Ya está solucionado gracias a @Devix, que me ha mostrado como capturar el evento para así modificarlo. Os dejo también aquí como capturar la pulsación que lo he encontrado a partir de que @Devix me diera la solución:

```
    @Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

añade este método en el método onCreate

```
 private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBar actionbar;

     private void setupToolbar() {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionbar != null) {
                actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
        }
```

Y posteriormente añade este metodo fuera del metodo onCreate

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Así es, muchas gracias, y buscando en base a lo tuyo he encontrado tambien como capturar como se realiza la pulsación al botón que es con onSupportNavigateUp(). De todos modos me gustaría seguir preguntando, porque no entiendo bien de todos modos. Aunque seguiré documentandome. La pregunta es, si yo no tengo ningún "menu" establecido en la Toolbar, a que hacer referencia el MenuItem que se pasa por parámetro?? En si la Toolbar es considerada un menu?? Perdonad, si pregunto barbaridades, acabo de empezar y los inicios son siempre duros =P

Comment: Un toolbar es considerado un view/barra de acciones, donde agregamos los elementos como el menú, si tu llegaras a descomentar  setSupportActionBar(toolbar); no se podria llamar a onOptionsItemSelected por que no estas instanciando nada a la vista

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que poner en el manifest su activity padre:

```
<activity
        android:name="activityname"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="activitypadre" />
 </activity>
```

Después en la activity tienes que activar el botón atrás:

```
   supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

El código está en Kotlin pero el procedimiento es el mismo.

Comment: Eso ya lo tengo puesto. Si como estar, el botón está y cuando lo pulso va hacía atrás. Quizás no me exprese bien, disculpen, pero yo lo que quiero saber es que método ejecuta el botón al ser pulsado.